# App is terminating because of timer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an app which deals with day to day activity. In my app user create some task to improve him/her. I'm using coredata to store data of user task.
In my app I have a NSTimer, and a selector - (void)Time_Update

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:40.0f target:self selector:@selector(Time_Update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

My app also have delete method for deleting task. The problem is when timer call and delete task occurs at same time my app crashes.
If anyone can help me with this problem. Ask me if you need any other information about it.
[This is crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT9Kv.png)

Comment: what is the crash log/stack trace ?

Comment: The crash is not related to the timer nor to its selector. The error clearly reveals that somewhere a range (0...10) of a 6-character string is going to be retrieved which raises an "out-of-bounds" exception.

Comment: @vadian Found the error. Thanks for your comment.